# To get Subversion to work with a remote client server, what do I need to do?

Tags: linux, networking, svn, code

What needs to be set up for a Linux server to checkout a Subversion repository from another Linux server? I have a Subversion instance installed with a repository on a server we'll call linuxSubversionServer. I have another Linux server on the same network that I want to be a client of the Subversion server. I tried this from the Linux client (we'll call LinuxClient).

$ svn checkout http://linuxSubversionServer.domain.com/usr/specialWR

(where specialWR is a repository)

I get this error:

svn 'http://linuxSubversionServer.domain.com/usr/specialWR' path not found.

Why a I getting this error? It has never worked.

Do I need apache on linuxSubversionServer to make the path to the repository presentable to a client server?

Do I need an agent or tool installed on LinuxClient?

Comment: Umm, yes, if you want to access the server using http, you need an http server running on it.  A quick google for subversion manual finds it and it explains different ways how to set up a server, one with apache, and one with the stand alone svn:// server: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 0):

> What needs to be set up for a Linux server to checkout a Subversion
>   repository from another Linux server?

1. Subversion needs to be installed on the client server and the Subversion repository server.
2. You cannot use the "http://" convention without Apache.  If you want to not install Apache, use "svn://" instead.

> Why a I getting this error?

Subversion isn't installed on the client.

> Do I need apache on linuxSubversionServer to make the path to the
>   repository presentable to a client server?

Yes, if you use http://.  No, if you can use svn://.

> Do I need an agent or tool installed on LinuxClient?

Yes, Subversion needs to be installed.